# xmlns в коде для класса

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть две `namespace`, Допустим `Root.NSA` и `Root.NSB`. В этих пространствах есть по два класса `A` и `B`. т.е. имеем четыре класса `Root.NSA.A`, `Root.NSA.B`, `Root.NSB.A`, `Root.NSB.B`.

Далее мы создаем окно `Windows` со следующим `XAML`:

```
<Window x:Class="PhoneStructure.ObjectShemeEdit"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ForNameSpace="clr-namespace:Root.NSA">
  <Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ForNameSpace:A}">
        ...
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ForNameSpace:B}">
        ...
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <TreeView ItemsSource="..."><!-- Элементы это экземпляры класса A и B, Темплейты подгружаются из ресурсов выше -->
  </TreeView>
</Window>
```

Все просто отлично, однако, мне необходимо создать такое же окно, с таким же расположением контролов, только с другим `xmlns:ForNameSpace`, а именно `xmlns:ForNameSpace="clr-namespace:Root.NSB"`.

Теперь собственно вопрос. Мне придется создавать 2 окна и контролировать идентичность кода `.cs` и `.XAML` или есть какое - то другое решение?

PS: использую в основном `{x:Static ForNameSpace:A.StaticProperty}`, `{x:Type ForNameSpace:A}`, `{x:Static ForNameSpace:B.StaticProperty}`, `{x:Type ForNameSpace:B}` и т.д.

PS2: Еще уточнение: Все классы наследуются от `Root.A` и `Root.B`, т.е.

```
class Root.NSA.A : Root.A
class Root.NSA.B : Root.B
class Root.NSB.A : Root.A
class Root.NSB.B : Root.B
```

Comment: А что конкретно из этих классов вы используете? DataSource/Binding использовать не получится?

Comment: @Андрей биндинги к статическим переменным и типам `{x:Static ForNameSpace:A.staticproperty}`, `{x:Type ForNameSpace:A}`

Comment: Используйте MVVM и биндите значения на VM. Во VM и будете поставлять объекты требуемыех классов.

Comment: @AGS17 если с `{x:Static ForNameSpace:A.staticproperty}` всё понятно, то как быть с `{x:Type ForNameSpace:A}`?

Comment: Статика, от нее у вас куча проблем. Она не дает вам использовать наследование. Если одно и то же представление у вас может биндиться к двум разным классам, значит эти классы реализуют какой-то общий интерфейс. Избавляйтесь от статики, выносите общую функциональность в интерфейс или (абстрактный) класс и наследуйтесь от него. Затем при создании представления просто передавайте нужный класс. Если ваш статик подразумевает единственность экземпляра - просто нужно создать эти экземпляры, например, в App и потом просто брать их оттуда при необходимости (либо Singetone, либо DI, либо ...)

Comment: @Андрей _Затем при создании представления просто передавайте нужный класс._ и как же? И проблема не в статике а в передачи биндингам типа `x:Type`!

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, ну как все делают... `var vmA = new Root.NSA.A(); var view = new MainWindow { DataSource = vmA };`

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик _И проблема не в статике_ - Статика сама по себе уже проблема. Слушайте Андрея.

Comment: @AGS17 @Андрей статические свойства не в корневом классе. Хорошо, уйдем от статики проблема с `{x:Type ForNameSpace:A}` всё равно останется.

Comment: Привел более развернутый пример, уже без статики, с ней как-нибудь справлюсь, проблема в другом.

Comment: Я честно не понимаю, чего вы хотите добиться этим - `{x:Type ForNameSpace:A}`. Если получать объект класса - ну и биндите его.

Comment: @AGS17 привел более развернуто пример

Comment: Подставьте пространство имен классов `Root.A` и `Root.B`. И биндите к объектам наследников.

Comment: @AGS17 в XAML это не прокатит `Root.NSA.A` и `Root.A` в `DataType` он будет считать совершенно разными и темплейт просто не будет подгружаться.

Comment: Да, точно. Значит вам придется явно приводить к типу базовых классов, либо клонировать к базовому типу. В общем могу с уверенностью сказать, что если и можно в рантайме сменить неймспейс - это очень плохой солюшн.

Comment: @AGS17 вот, теперь Вы меня понимаете =) сейчас пробую через дататемплейтселектор сделать...

Comment: Точно! DataTemplateSelector - лучший вариант на мой взгляд. Вот вы сами и ответили на свой вопрос :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ForNameSpace:A}"/>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ForNameSpace:B}"/>
...
```

переименовал в

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="r_A"/>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="r_B"/>
...
```

добавил `DataTemplateSelector`

```
public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
  {
    string key = "r_" + item.GetType().Name;
    DependencyObject root = null;
    DependencyObject next = container;
    while (next != null)
    {
      root = next;
      next = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(root);
    }
    if ((root as FrameworkElement).Resources.Contains(key))
      return (root as FrameworkElement).Resources[key] as DataTemplate;
    return null;
  }
}
```

также в класс окна добавил свойство

```
public MyDataTemplateSelector DataTemplateSelector { get; } = new MyDataTemplateSelector();
```

и обозвал окно

```
<Window ...
        Name="f_MyWindow">
  ...
</Window>
```

теперь во всех контролах, где использую шаблоны добавил

```
ItemTemplateSelector="{Binding ElementName=f_MyWindow, Path=DataTemplateSelector}"
```

и вуаля, неважно какой `namespace` у класса во `ViewModel`, главное чтобы имя класса совпадало с `r_[имя класса]`. Можно еще было в `MyDataTemplateSelector` проверить является ли потомком класса `Root.A` или `Root.B`, но у меня не стояла в этом задача.

ЗЫ: префикс `r_` можно заменить на любой другой, особой разницы нет.